# Diamond + rawtype doesn't compile on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors, raw-types, diamond-operator

The following code fails to compile on Eclipse Neon 4.6.0 :

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {

   @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     Map rawMap = new HashMap();
     Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>(rawMap); // Type mismatch: cannot convert from HashMap to Map<String, Integer>
     map = Collections.synchronizedMap(rawMap); // No error here
   }

}
```

The exact same code compiles fine when invoking javac (1.8) from the command line. It also works on older versions of Eclipse (Mars 2). What is the issue here?

Comment: What's the issue that means you have to use raw types in the first place?

Comment: Stricter typing is the case. Unfortunately the typing becoming so complex the compilers' programming becomes fragmentary. It here and now recognizes that in a typed context (`<>`) a raw map is added.

Comment: This works fine for me on Eclipse Neon.

Comment: @AndyTurner in the actual code, the raw map comes from an external library. By the way, I know how to change the code to make it work, but I would like to know why this 3 years old code started to fail.